# Embedding multiple packages in python like wxpython ,networkX,matpolotlib

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, networkx, graphviz, software-design

I need a suggestion regarding building an application, I have to build an application that must be having an basic GUI elements and with scematic editor ( where i have to automatically generate the network with different objects( supposing them as nodes) from the given data in **xml**

Till now I have extracted the data and connections information of network for the given data file in python. Now I need to display the network diagram in schematic of a application.

I am bit new to the python packages , so I am thinking of like by embedding **networkX/Graphviz** package, **wxpython**  and  by using the info of connections I extracted, thinking to start coding for my goal

Can it be able to satisfy my gui requirement and schematic editor ?

I know its not an easy task, my aim is not to complete this atleast to contribute something that may be useful to others for updating my work.

**Suggest something that u feel it might be useful for my work and guide me if I am going in wrong way **!

** I am adding a pic of  probable schematic type and UI to make things clear what am I need to do!** 
schematic (network) that is in the pic.2  must be the output of my program that has to displayed on canvas of the application.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another fellow EAGLE user! Well, modern EAGLE schematics are stored in XML format, along with library information of the parts used in the schematic.  And, the connection information for the parts is also part of the XML.  So if you can parse all that with python as you say, and leave out anything extraneous, it should be possible.  Intriguing idea.

Basically you'd treat EAGLE pins as dot/graphviz nodes.  And you'd treat EAGLE nets as dot/graphviz edges.  Write the dot file and render in the dot engine of your choice.  Lots of interesting possibilities with your idea.

Comment: No i am not asking how to add image to schematic of eagle, My aim is to build an software that must be area for schematic and gui elements in a single window like the picture shown above. As above I said i have to generate the network diagram in canvas of gui application, i am thinking to do with importing wxpython and networkX . Do it satisfy my requirement i am asking thats all!!

Comment: Changed my answer completely based on your clarification.

Comment: okay thanks for the information that even eagle schematic files are stored in xml i.e they also generated by parsing it. But, my major doubt is that can i bring the graph or network in the canvas of the gui made from the wxpython in a single window like we see in eagle simulation software where we have buttons and schematic diagram in a single page?

Comment: Can we draw edges of L shaped for joining two nodes rather than straight line , can we control the path of edge for joining nodes using that dot graphviz? @JLH

Comment: @Nikhil  You can influence the path of edges in dot, but I think you cannot control them to the degree you seem to want.  It's not really a drafting tool, it's a tool for visualizing graphs (in the mathematical sense) of nodes and edges.  Different layout engines visualize the graphs in different ways, but I don't think you'll ultimately get what you want from dot.

Comment: Thanks for concluding that we can't do we this , else  I would have been tried some programs for checking this. you saved my time @JLH !!